# Time-out error when I try to synchronize the app for the first time

Tags: android, synchronization, timeout, okhttp, interrupted-exception

I'm working in a code that download all the information from the server when you sign in for the first time. The point is when you try to sync the app the first time always launch a time-out error, and then when you try again, the process work successfully. 
We've checked the server and there is no problem there. Also we have an iOS app that works fine.
we are using gson streaming and okhttp request to sync the data.

For the last, I can't debug the response I don't know why.

Any ideas or recommendations?

Thank you so much!

Comment: please could you show us your code?

Comment: It's hard to guess what might have gone wrong without access to actual code which falls into this problem. You can try to create [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)([How to ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), section "Help others reproduce the problem") to allow us to examine this problem. You can also use [logcat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html) to provide a stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but I think that show you the code will be useless, because there are about 4 or 5 classes involved with a lot of lines. I'm keep working on it but nothing for now.